# MongoDB : does Collection.Find() support promise

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was trying to revamp an old Nodejs web service to replace callback functions with chained promises.
When querying mongodb we used the syntax below to iterate through a result set.

```
collection.find(filter).toArray(function(err, items) {
          if (err) {
            throw(err);
          } else {
            console.log(items);

          }
```

If I try to replace the `.toArray()` section with a `.then()` I get the below error "col.find(...).then is not a function".

If I replace `.find()` with `.findOne().then()`, the code works perfectly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can do `collection.find(<query>, function(err, arrayOfData) {})`

Comment: or you can promisify using the require('util').promisify function

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I am want to use promises

Comment: that works like a promise does, it only goes into the function once the query has finished

Comment: @Zorgatone I will try to make further research on require('util').promisify thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`find` returns a `Cursor`, but the cursor's `toArray` method returns a promise. So you can do:

```
collection.find(filter).toArray().then(...)
```

Comment: Looks like it does return a Promise in newer versions of the nodejs mongodb driver api, but it didn’t in earlier versions

Comment: @Zorgatone It's had support for promises for a couple years now; even going back to the 2.x releases.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using mongoosejs.

collection.find() is just a query.  To cause it to execute and return a promise, you need to call .exec() on it.:

```
collection.find(filter).exec()
    .then(items => console.log(items))
    .catch(err => { // handle error })
```

The mongoose docs give you more details on how to use mongoose with either callbacks or promises:  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: OP should specify which package is using

Comment: But I believe it’s plain official mongo driver

Comment: Funny, I've been using mongoose so long I hadn't noticed mongodb made their own.